# Loading all codeigniter controller at the beginning

Tags: codeigniter, controller, load

I've a little problem.

In a controller i will load a function wich is in otherController.

I just use

```
$pCtrl = new otherController;
```

for loading the class in that otherController.

The problem is that at that moment the otherController has not already been loaded. So the class is not available.

Can i find a way to tell codeigniter to load all controllers (folder controller) before doing other thing ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bad practice. You should be using a CodeIgniter Library to do this instead.

Though, if you're already doing bad things, you could just open the /controllers directory in your config/autoload.php and configure codeigniter to autoload all available controllers. Not sure if this will work well (and efficiently) in practice, so try using libraries.

Comment: Hello, you're right. It's certainly not the best thing to do. The best thing for me would be just having the possibilily to choose the order of controller load. I need one controller for some type of content but not always the same. If i can say: i want this controller load first (another one from this called by url), it will be optimal for me.

Comment: I don't remember if CI has a controller loading order option.. Actually, if you just need that controller for some of these, you could actually create a "base" with all the functions you need for that, and then make your controllers extend (therefore inherit) that "base" class instead. Yes, not the best thing to do either. You should really consider using a library or helper.

Comment: Another solution is just to load my controller with a require_once. Perhaps the simpliest solution for me

Comment: Yes, but that would be awfully bad. You're making more problems than you could solve with CI.. Sadly. Really, try learning Libraries if you have time. I learned this the hard way first time when I played with CI and CakePHP. *Lots* of wasted development time. Doing what? Rewriting to adhere to standards/best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to create a helper function or a library ..

oh btw , you can use [HMVC](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/) also .

Comment: I will see HMVC, don't know it. Thanks